# Concise Way of Constructing Create Class with Many Fields?

Tags: scala

Given a case class:

```
scala> case class Foo(a: String, b: String, c: String, d: String, 
                       e: String, f: Int, g: String, h: String, i: Int)
defined class Foo
```

I have a function: `f: Foo => Int`, and I need to test that `f(Foo) == 1`.

Is there a concise way, for testing purposes, to create a case class (without defining each field)?

I considered making the field lazily evaluated and then using `???`, but:

```
scala> case class Bar(a: => Int)
<console>:1: error: `val' parameters may not be call-by-name
case class Foo(a: => Int)
                  ^
```

**EDIT**

I'm requesting an answer that does not include default parameters.

Comment: You can use function literals as parameters for case classes: `case class Foo(a: () => Int)`. But I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Do you need to create just one instance or the ability to create several instances for testing without giving all parameters?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if something like this is what you want, but:

```
% sbt                                                                                                     
...
> set scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
...
> set libraryDependencies += "org.cvogt" %% "scalacheck-extensions" % "0.2"
...
> console
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.7 (...)
...

scala> case class Foo(a: String, b: String, c: String, i: Int)
defined class Foo

scala> import org.cvogt.scalacheck.GenTree
import org.cvogt.scalacheck.GenTree

scala> case class Foo(a: String, b: Double, c: Int)
defined class Foo

scala> GenTree.partialTree[Foo].sample
res0: Option[Foo] = Some(Foo(ᐊ沄⎤...,8.646125633001667E248,0))
```

awwwww yeah

Answer (score 1):

You can give default values to all parameters and create a `Foo` with just the one you want:

```
case class Foo(a : String = "", b : String = "", c : String = "" ... )
```

Then you can create a `Foo` with all default values

```
val f = Foo()
```

or create one with specific parameters

```
val f = Foo(a = "a", b = "b")   // the rest will have the default values
```

Comment: I'll update my question to exclude default parameters

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you exclude default values, but if you need a different default value for each of the cases you construct a Foo instance, then I think, what you need is a factory object. Something like this maybe:

```
object FooFactory {
  def apply(a: String): Foo = Foo(a, "b", ... "k", 1)
  def apply(b: String): Foo = Foo("a1", b, ... "k1", 2)
  //add an apply overload for every combination you need
}
```